# Table won't display and Sql won't run

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session

For some reason my table I'm trying to create doesn't show up on my page. The page use to work perfectly and I can't figure out why its not working now.

My program only works when I set

```
$_SESSION['loginname']="jordan@yahoo.com"; 
or $_SESSION['loginname']="mary666@yahoo.com";
```

and so on.

I've already started a "$_Session" on my previous page with the name `$_SESSION['loginname'];` I've echoed out the Session over and over to see if it is passing right from one page to another and down the current page and it does.

Why isn't my $_SESSION allowing my MYSQL code to run the loop to display my data from my database? code provided below:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>

<head>
  <title>User Account</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" /> 
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main">

    <header>
      <div id="welcome">
        <h2>Prairie View A&amp;M University</h2>
      </div><!--close welcome-->                
    </header>   

    <nav>
      <div id="menubar">
        <ul id="nav">
          <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
          <li class="current"><a href="user-account.php">Account Info</a></li>
          <li><a href="quiz_main.php">Quiz</a></li>
          &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
<?php
if($_SESSION['loginname'])
echo $_SESSION['loginname'].", "."<a href='user-account.php'>Account</a>"."     "."<a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";

else
    die("You must login");
?>
        </ul>
      </div><!--close menubar-->    
    </nav>      

    <div id="site_content">

   <?php
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$hostname = "localhost";
$database = "basketball_database";
$table = "users";

$session_login = $_SESSION['loginname'];

$con = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
 or die("Unable to connect to MYsql");
// echo "Connected to mysql<br>";

 mysql_select_db("$database")
 or die("Could not select Basketball_database");
 //echo "Connected to database";

 $mysql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE login_name='$_SESSION[loginname]'";


 $mydata = mysql_query($mysql,$con);

 while($records = mysql_fetch_array($mydata)){
 //create table
 echo "<table border=1
 <tr>
 <th>User ID</th></tr>
 <tr>
 <th>Login Name</th></tr>
 <tr>
 <th>Password</th></tr>
 <tr>
 <th>Last Name</th></tr>
 <tr>
 <th>First Name</th></tr>
 <tr>
 <th>Account Type</th>
 </tr>";



     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td>".$records['user_ID']."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$records['login_name']."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$records['password']."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$records['last_name']."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$records['first_name']."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$records['type']."</td>";
     echo "</tr>";       
 } echo "</table>";

 mysql_close();
?>

      <div id="content">
        <div class="content_item">


      </div><!--close content_container-->          
    </div><!--close content_item-->
</div><!--close content-->   
    </div><!--close site_content-->     

    <footer>
     <a href="index.php">Home</a> | <a href="photos.php">Photos</a> | <a href="videos.php">Videos</a> | <a href="schedule.php">Schedule</a> | <a href="contact.php">Contact</a><br/><br/>

    </footer>   

  </div><!--close main-->

  <!-- javascript at the bottom for fast page loading -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/image_slide.js"></script>  

</body>
</html>
```

I do realize that my table is going to look like this

```
User ID
Login Name
Password
Last Name
First Name
Account Type
1321  jordan@yahoo.com  21duncan   oneal  jordan   athlete
```

Comment: You are creating table in the loop, which will cause HTML mess. Move your table declaration above while loop.

Comment: I originally had it like you said but my table headers appear but the data doesn't show. I've ran the sql code through my phpmyadmin and I was able to select the data I wanted. But some reason my sql code isnt running.

Comment: It sounds like your tests and conclusions are wrong. You say the session variable is filled in your current script, and the SQL is okay, and you don't get output, but you do when you set the $_SESSION['loginname'] variable yourself (to the value that it already has).. That seems very unlikely. Please test again and strip down the code to a more minimal example.

Comment: when I echo `$_SESSION['loginname']` in the second `<?php` tage I get 'jordan@yahoo.com' I repeat this process in the third `<?php` tag and I get the same results. I then `echo $mysql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE login_name='$_SESSION[loginname]'";` and get a result of `SELECT * FROM users WHERE login_name=jordan@yahoo.com`. I then copy `SELECT * FROM users WHERE login_name=jordan@yahoo.com` and run SQL query in phpmyadmin and get the results 1321 jordan@yahoo.com 21duncan...and so on.

Comment: so I don't understand why my data isnt being displayed in my table. Note that this code hasn't been changed and has recently stopped working for an unknown reason.